# PortableText Typescript Error with Sanity.Io in Nextjs Application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, sanity

I am upgrading my NextJs/Sanity application to NextJS 13 using Sanity.io and typescript.

The PortableText tag no longer works. The value and components attributes are flagged as an error in Visual Studio Code.

```
<PortableText value={post?.body} components={components} />
```

I am getting the error:

Type 'PortableTextBlockComponent[]' is not assignable to type 'TypedObject | TypedObject[]'.
Type 'PortableTextBlockComponent[]' is not assignable to type 'TypedObject[]'.
Type 'PortableTextBlockComponent' is not assignable to type 'TypedObject'.
Property '_type' is missing in type 'ComponentClass<PortableTextComponentProps<PortableTextBlock<PortableTextMarkDefinition, ArbitraryTypedObject | PortableTextSpan, string, string>>, any>' but required in type 'TypedObject'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(171, 3): '_type' is declared here.
react-portable-text.d.ts(163, 3): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PortableTextProps'
(property) PortableTextProps.value: TypedObject | TypedObject[]

Here is what i am importing:

```
import { PortableText } from "@portabletext/react";
```

I also have an error on the IMG tag - URLFor attribute when defining the components.

```
onst components = {
    types: {
        image: ({ value }) => {
            if (!value?.asset?._ref) {
                return null;
            }
            return (
                <img
                    alt={value.alt || " "}
                    loading="lazy"
                    src={urlFor(value).width(320).height(240).fit("max").auto("format")}
                />
            );
        },
    },
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.